# The given path's format is not supported in Isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to calculate my file size before uploading in server, before that I keep my file in Isolated storage by creating a folder. Now I want to get the path for calculating file size, but it is giving error "The given path's format is not supported"

My Code Is:

```C#
string filePath = Path.Combine(FolderName, FileName);
string fp = @"ms-appdata:///local//" + imageFolder + "//" + fName; // here I tried "/" and try to append "filePath " directly still throwing same error

FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fp); ////Here it is throwing error "The given path's format is not supported"

var fileLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(fp).Length;
int image_file_size = Convert.ToInt32(fileLength);
```

What is the correct format for this path?

Comment: Does this work for you: 'Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)'

Comment: Now I am getting error operation not supported in this platform :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that kind of path is when you're sourcing your code in XAML.  If you want to do with System.IO

Then you need to build the path like this

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");   
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(dbPath);
```

---

[image]

Comment: Wow its working, thanks a lot Chubosaurus Software :) 

 string FilePath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filePath);
                        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(FilePath);
                        var fileLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath).Length;

Answer (score 1):

This code is working properly

```C#
string filePath = Path.Combine(FolderName, FileName);
string FilePath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filePath);
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(FilePath);
var fileLength = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath).Length;
int image_file_size = Convert.ToInt32(fileLength);
```